# paypal express checkout guest checkout not working

Tags: paypal

i have used same paypal business account and it's credentials for two different sites. For both it goes to paypal site where first one shows "Continue" button but second one shows "Agree and create Account" button(For Guest Checkout). which means that, guest checkout is not working for second one. here is first and second nvpsrt for you. please let me to figure out.

First NVPSTR:

```
&L_NAME0=Know Thyself&L_NAME1=Path To Nirvana&L_AMT0=3.00&L_AMT1=9.00&L_QTY0=2&L_QTY1=2&MAXAMT=56&AMT=31&ITEMAMT=24&CALLBACKTIMEOUT=4&ADDRESSOVERRIDE=0&SHIPTONAME=True Seeker&SHIPTOSTREET=111, Bliss Ave&SHIPTOCITY=San Jose&SHIPTOSTATE=CA&SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=US&SHIPTOZIP=95128&NOSHIPPING=0&SHIPPINGAMT=8&SHIPDISCAMT=-3&TAXAMT=2&SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole&L_NUMBER0=1000&L_DESC0=Size: 8.8-oz&L_NUMBER1=10001&L_DESC1=Size: Two 24-piece boxes&L_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE1=0.5&L_ITEMWEIGHTUNIT1=lbs&ReturnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A80%2Fpaypal_multiple_product%2FReviewOrder.php%3FcurrencyCodeType%3DUSD%26paymentType%3DSale&CANCELURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A80%2Fpaypal_multiple_product%2FSetExpressCheckout.php%3FpaymentType%3DSale&CURRENCYCODE=USD&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&LOGOIMG=http://localhost/randd/paypal_multiple_product/images/logo.gif&useraction=commit
```

Second NVPSTR:

```
&L_NAME0=Lice Treatment&L_AMT0=15.00&L_QTY0=1&L_NUMBER0=12&L_DESC0=test&MAXAMT=48.5&AMT=23.5&ITEMAMT=15&CALLBACKTIMEOUT=4&ADDRESSOVERRIDE=0&SHIPTONAME=Jackson Pollick&SHIPTOSTREET=440 Benmar Suite 204&SHIPTOCITY=Dallas&SHIPTOSTATE=&SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=US&SHIPTOZIP=77060&NOSHIPPING=0&SHIPPINGAMT=8.5&SHIPDISCAMT=0&TAXAMT=0&ReturnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amysallnaturals.com%3A80%2Fpaypal_multiple_product%2FReviewOrder.php%3FcurrencyCodeType%3DUSD%26paymentType%3DSale&CANCELURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amysallnaturals.com%3A80%2Fpaypal_multiple_product%2FSetExpressCheckout.php%3FpaymentType%3DSale&CURRENCYCODE=USD&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&LOGOIMG=http://www.amysallnaturals.com/images/logo.gif&useraction=commit
```

moreover if you need anything else to know please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasons why Guest checkout is not showing up. You must have a verified Business or Premier PayPal Account.

If you have a verified Business/Premier PayPal Account then according to the PayPal Documentation you can pass these two parameters in your Express Checkout Call:

`SOLUTIONTYPE= Sole` (Optional) Type of checkout flow.

Sole – Buyer does not need to create a PayPal account to check out. This is referred to as PayPal Account Optional.

You can set up the Landing Page to default to this:

```
LANDINGPAGE= Billing
```

(Optional) Type of PayPal page to display.

Billing – Non-PayPal account

This comes from the PayPal Developer site. Just in case you need it here is the direct link to the PayPal Developer Site with this information:

[Express Checkout API Operation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)